# Put button in same position in boxes with different sizes

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using an image gallery. Each image has different sizes, masonry style. How can I place a button inside each image in the same position with different sizes? I want to put the button in the upper right corner.

**css**

```
.EyeG{
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white; 
  background-image: url("/assets/eye.svg");
  background-position: 13px 13px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 15%;
  width: 15%;
  margin-top: -329px;
  right: 13px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ngx-masonry [options]="masonryOptions" [useImagesLoaded]="true">
        <ngxMasonryItem *ngFor="let p of products" class="masonry-item">      
      </div>
          <img [src]="imagMap.get(p.id)">
          <figcaption class="EyeG"></figcaption>
        </ngxMasonryItem>
      </ngx-masonry>
```

Comment: You used % for height and width, why don't you use % for the position of the EyeG too? That could help you position it following the dimension of the image

Comment: Does not result in box placement :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.masonry-item { position: relative }
.EyeG{
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white; 
  background-image: url("/assets/eye.svg");
  background-position: 13px 13px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 15%;
  width: 15%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  opacity: 1;
 top:50%;
left:50%;
transfomrm: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Attached codepen link, please have look.

Let me know if you not got your solution here. Will help you

```
<div class="header">
  <h1>Responsive Masonry.js Grid</h1>
  <p>A horizontal image card grid built with masonry.js</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
  <a class="item" href="#">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/350x300">
    <sapn class="EyeG"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="item" href="#">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/350x200">
    <sapn class="EyeG"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="item" href="#">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x290">
    <sapn class="EyeG"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="item" href="#">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/400x300">
    <sapn class="EyeG"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="item" href="#">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/350x350">
    <sapn class="EyeG"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="item" href="#">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/400x300">
    <sapn class="EyeG"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="item" href="#">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/400x500">
    <sapn class="EyeG"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/pgurav/pen/zYYXoNj